Why google play billis are async inside newSingleThreadExecutor and the code does not work?
I have an activity where I pull data from Google Play Bills Api in and put on screen with help of an adapter. I'm trying to make the data to be passed from the getProductsQuery() to refreshPurchaseRecycler() function.
    import com.package.databinding.ActivityPurchaseBinding
    import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams
    import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener
    import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient
    import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener
    import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams
    import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult
    import com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetails
    import com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase
    import com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener
    import com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams
    import java.io.IOException
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors
    
    
    class PurchaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnPurchaseItemClickListener { //}, PurchasesUpdatedListener {
        private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient
        private lateinit var productSubscription: String
        private lateinit var productInApp: String
    
        private var isSuccess = false
        var premiumActive: Boolean = false
        lateinit var premiumPreferences: SharedPreferences
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityPurchaseBinding
    
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_purchase)
            binding.purchaseItemsRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar!!.title = getString(R.string.remove_ads)
    
            println("DEBUG Subs: on create")
            initBillingClient()
            productSubscription = "package_no_ads"
            productInApp = "package_no_ads_forever"
    
    
            premiumPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Premium", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            premiumActive = premiumPreferences.getBoolean("premiumActive", false)
    
            getProductsQuery()
        }
    
        private fun initBillingClient(){
            println("DEBUG Subs: initBillingClient")
            billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build()
        }
        private val purchasesUpdatedListener =
            PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
                println("DEBUG Subs: purchasesUpdatedListener")
                if(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "billingResult OK, without purchases", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    println("DEBUG Subs: billing client OK!")
                    println("DEBUG Subs: $purchases")
                    for (purchase in purchases){
                        handlePurchase(purchase)
                    }
                } else if(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Already Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
                } else if(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "FEATURE NOT SUPPORTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else if(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "USER CANCELED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else if(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "BILLING UNAVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else if(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.NETWORK_ERROR){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "NETWORK ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error "+billingResult.debugMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
    
            }
        private fun verifyValidSignature(signedData: String, signature: String): Boolean {
            return try {
                val security = Security()
                val base64Key = "*******"
                security.verifyPurchase(base64Key, signedData, signature)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                false
            }
        }
    
        private var acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener { billingResult ->
            if(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                isSuccess = true
            }
        }
        private fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase){
            if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED){
                if(!verifyValidSignature(purchase.originalJson, purchase.signature)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Purchase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    return
                }
                if(!purchase.isAcknowledged){
                    val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                        .build()
                    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener)
                    isSuccess = true
                    finish()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Already Subscribe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }else if(purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING){
                Toast.makeText(this, "PENDING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else if(purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE){
                Toast.makeText(this, "UNSPECIFIED STATE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        private fun refreshPurchaseRecycler(productsList: MutableList<MutableMap<String, Any>>){
    
            println("DEBUG Subs: refreshRecycler: refreshPurchaseRecycler called")
            println("DEBUG Subs: refreshRecycler: $productsList")
            runOnUiThread {
                binding.emptyList.text = getString(R.string.loading_bills)
                binding.purchaseItemsRecycler.adapter = PurchaseAdapter(this, productsList, this)
                println("DEBUG Subs: refreshRecycler: refreshPurchaseRecycler runOnUiThread")
    
                if(productsList.isEmpty()) {
                    println("DEBUG Subs: refreshRecycler: productsAdapterList.isEmpty")
                    binding.purchaseItemsRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.emptyList.text = getString(R.string.no_premium_available)
                    binding.emptyList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }else if(premiumActive){
                    println("DEBUG Subs: refreshRecycler: premiumActive")
                    binding.purchaseItemsRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.emptyList.text = getString(R.string.using_premium)
                    binding.emptyList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    println("DEBUG Subs: refreshRecycler: load purchases")
                    binding.purchaseItemsRecycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.emptyList.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
    
        }
    
        private fun getProductsQuery(){
            billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
                override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {}
                override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    println("DEBUG Subs: billingResult.responseCode: ${billingResult.responseCode}")
                    println("DEBUG Subs: billingResult.responseCode: ${(billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)}")
                    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        println("DEBUG Subs: billingResult.responseCode OK")
    
                        val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    //                    executorService.execute {
                        var productsAdapterList = mutableListOf<MutableMap<String, Any>>()
                        executorService.submit {
                            println("DEBUG Subs: billingResult executorService")
                            var productDetailsMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
                            val subsQueryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(
                                listOf(
                                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                    .setProductId(productSubscription)
                                    .build()
                                )
                            ).build()
                            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                                subsQueryProductDetailsParams
                            ) { _, productDetailsList ->
                                val productDetails = productDetailsList[0]
                                println("DEBUG Subs: before for loop subs bills")
                                println("DEBUG Subs: ${productDetails.subscriptionOfferDetails}")
                                var i = 0;
                                for(productPlan in productDetails.subscriptionOfferDetails!!) {
                                    i++
                                    productDetailsMap["productDetails"] = productDetails
                                    productDetailsMap["productPlans"] = productPlan
    
                                    productsAdapterList.add(productDetailsMap)
                                    println("DEBUG Subs: productSubsDetails $i")
                                }
                                println("DEBUG Subs: after for loop - productSubsDetails $i")
                            }
    
                            println("DEBUG Subs: productsAdapterList before inAppQueryProduct: $productsAdapterList")
    
                            val inAppQueryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(
                                listOf(
                                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                                    .setProductId(productInApp)
                                    .build()
                                )
                            ).build()
                            println("DEBUG Subs: inapp build ok")
    
                            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                                inAppQueryProductDetailsParams
                            ) { _, productDetailsList ->
                                println("DEBUG Subs: inapp query product")
                                val productDetails = productDetailsList[0]
                                productDetailsMap["productDetails"] = productDetails
                                productDetailsMap["productPlans"] = {}
                                productsAdapterList.add(productDetailsMap)
                                println("DEBUG Subs: productInAppDetails: $productDetails")
                            }
    
                            println("DEBUG Subs: productSubsDetails in the end, inside execute: $productsAdapterList")
                            refreshPurchaseRecycler(productsAdapterList)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }






To debug the getProductsQuery() in production, I've used a third-app to see the printlns. Here is the sequence of the logs in the images. The order is different from the sequence of println inside executorService.submit. I've tried with executorService.execute, but the result is the same. Why it happens and why the productsAdapterList variable is passed empty to refreshPurchaseRecycler() function?
